# Is it to soon to apply for an internal job posting?

Tags: internal-transfer

So I've been working for the this company for around 4 years. About 6 months ago I started a new job within the company because it fit my school schedule better. Recently I found out about a possible opening in a position that would have more to do with my education, but I'm worried that it's too soon. I like my current position, but think I would enjoy the new one more.

Is there a good way to bring up applying for this new position with my manager, or is it too soon to do anything?

Comment: Do you know whether there are internal policies about how soon you can change positions?

Answer (score 4):

> Recently I found out about a possible opening in a position that would
>   have more to do with my education, but I'm worried that it's too soon.
>   I like my current position, but think I would enjoy the new one more.
>
> Is there a good way to bring up applying for this new position with my
>   manager, or is it too soon to do anything?

Many companies have a written policy regarding how frequently you can apply for internal positions. The duration I have seen most often is 1 year.

Check if your company has such a policy. If they do, follow it. If not, talk to HR and learn if there is an "informal policy". If no policy, then go ahead and apply.

If you do go forward and apply, try not to do this too often. You may inadvertently end up coming across as someone who is high maintenance, who will jump quickly and never be happy too long. Sort of an "internal job-hopper". Managers tend to frown on that. Once in a while might make sense, but not too often.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a good way to bring up applying for this new position with my
>   manager, or is it too soon to do anything?

As Joe stated, you do not want to do this too often and check your company policy for any restrictions.

**If** there aren't company policies preventing you from applying *consider* the following advise:

In your case, you seem to have a *pretty compelling reason* to want to make the change positions as you are still working on completing your education.

I would suggest you have an *open and honest* conversation with your manager.  Most managers I know **would** be open to this type of move because it helps you and in the long term might help the company retain you long term.

Of course, there are a ton of factors to consider from the managers perspective (like their obligations for example) that might make your request painful to them.  Consider having a **transition plan** ready to discuss if you choose to and are able to have this conversation.